# Shaders management

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

I am learning about GLSL in order to manage it in my IOS & android C++ engine.
I get a lot of documentation about syntax and GLSL programming but I need some tutorials about how to manage it in a complete scene (How to apply a shader only on a specific object of the scene ? How combine several effects on an object ? )

Do you have some links or book reference to send me ?

Comment: A nice introductory site explaining the GLSL is: http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/glsl/

Comment: @boto I guess that's not what he's looking for. He rather wants suggestions on a good scene management architecture, which is why this question is a bit too broad to answer appropriately.

Comment: Yes, this is why I ask for documentation instead of a specific answer. The orange book is very useful for learn how to write shaders but doesn't give the way to manage it in a game framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to apply a shader only on a specific object of the scene ?

It's the same way you apply a texture to a specific object. You call `glUseProgram` with the program you want to use. Any subsequent rendering commands will use that program, until another `glUseProgram` call is encountered.

> How combine several effects on an object ?

In general, this means that you write a new shader. Shaders are not really things you can combine with the API. You can copy bits of them into other shaders. You can use the [unique features of the OpenGL shader object paradigm](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Object) to change program functionality based on which programs are linked to which.

But in the general case, if you want to combine several "effects", you have to write a new shader that has those effects in it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was the first problem I encounter to create my first shader manager.